# Remove all children from container

Tags: actionscript-3

I try to remove all children from the `AvatarShow` container but it is not working.
Can you help me?

```
for (var i:int = AvatarShow.numChildren-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    AvatarShow.removeChildAt(i);
}
```

Comment: What is AvatarShow? Is it a class, or an object, or the name of something on the stage?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 while(AvatarShow.numChildren >0)
    {
      AvatarShow.removeChildAt(0);
    }
```

Also

You can use

```
AvatarShow.removeAllChildren()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its not Work...

removeAllChildren is not define and the while not work!

Comment: There is no `removeAllChildren()` method. There is a Flex method called `removeAllElements()`, but you can only use that on Flex `Group`s

Comment: @JoshJanusch The correct name of the method is `removeChildren()`, it accepts an index range with defaults being 0 through 0x7fffffff aka all elements.

Comment: @Vesper Right you are, I forgot about that. That was only added in Flash Player 11, though, so be careful about using it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have graphics data on your symbol try

```
// remove all children
for (var i:int = AvatarShow.numChildren-1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    AvatarShow.removeChildAt(i);
}
// clear graphics
AvatarShow.graphics.clear();
```

Or if you don't need your avatarShow you can do:

```
AvatarShow.parent.removeChild( AvatarShow );
```

Just a little thing more, if you can use upercase first letters only for class name and keep lowercase first letter for variable, it's better (ex: MyClassName, myVariableName) ;)

Comment: i think it would be better to give us more information about your problem